# how to call procedure with out parameter as table type from a java class (2)

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

the answer seams already to be answered here:
[how to call procedure with out parameter as table type from a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621638/how-to-call-procedure-with-out-parameter-as-table-type-from-a-java-class)

But we have the problem, that returned value vor code is always "???", value for trxSeq is returned correctly.
If we call it directly on db, code is filled with value.

We tried code as type varchar2, char, varchar. No difference.

```
desc t_mam_code:
       TYPE t_mam_code AS OBJECT(                              
         code VARCHAR2(30),                                                
         trxSeq NUMBER(12)
```

java method

```
final String typeName = "T_MAM_CODE";
final String typeTableName = "T_MAM_CODE_TAB";

// no difference, if we use Oracle Connection or java.sql.Connection
OracleConnection oracleConnection= connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

// Get a description of your type (Oracle specific)
final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName, oracleConnection);
final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();

CallableStatement call = oracleConnection.prepareCall("{call business.getCodes(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
// CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{call business.getCodes(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");

int i = 1;
call.setString(i++, shopId);
call.setDate(i++, new java.sql.Date(consumerStamp.getTime()));
call.setInt(i++, version);
...

int out1 = i++;

call.registerOutParameter(out1, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);
//call.registerOutParameter(out1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, typeTableName);

call.execute();

Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) call.getObject(out1)).getArray();
for(Object tmp : data) {
  Struct row = (Struct) tmp;
  // Attributes are index 1 based...
  int idx = 1;
  for(Object attribute : row.getAttributes()) {               
     System.out.println(metaData.getColumnName(idx) + " " + attribute);                                            
     ++idx;
}
```

Output is:

```
CODE ??? 
TRXSEQ 200001520606 ...
```

Output should be:

```
CODE ABC1234 
TRXSEQ 200001520606
```

We use Java 1.6, Oracle 11g, Driver ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar through hibernate 4.1.12

Comment: Guess it's encoding problem, Are there any garbled characters while using direct select query for that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for hint didxga - you put us into right direction. We added orai18n.jar to classpath and now everything works fine :)