# JDBC OUT parameter as array

Tags: java, oracle

I have this stored proc with the below signature, i want to register it as out parameter but gives me this error:

**error:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'car_details_ins'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'car_details_ins'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**sproc:**

```
PROCEDURE car_details_ins
   (
      car_details IN car_details_tab_type
     ,id                   IN NUMBER
     ,user                      IN VARCHAR2
     ,app_id               OUT number_tab_type
     ,error_tab           OUT car_error_tab_type
   )
```

**Java:**

```
public void save(String DataSource,int Id,String username) throws SQLException{
        Connection con = getConnection(DataSource);
        CallableStatement cs= con.prepareCall({call pckg.save_details(?,?,?,?,?)});

    Object[] project1 = new Object[]{AWO,"LAM,1,"SEDAN"};
    Object[] project2 = new Object[]{AWO,"LAM,1,"SEDAN"};

    StructDescriptor projectTypeDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("CAR_DETAILS_TAB_TYPE", con);
    STRUCT structProject1 = new STRUCT(projectTypeDesc, con, project1);//THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    STRUCT structProject2 = new STRUCT(projectTypeDesc, con, project2);

    STRUCT[] structArrayOfProjects = {structProject1,structProject2};
     ArrayDescriptor projectTypeArrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CAR_DETAILS_TAB_TYPE", con);
     ARRAY arrayOfProjects = new ARRAY(projectTypeArrayDesc, con, structArrayOfProjects);       

        cs.setArray(1, details);
        cs.setInt(2, Id);
        cs.setString(3, username);

        cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
        cs.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
        cs.execute();

    }
```

is there any other way of providing:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
            cs.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
```

adding for more details.
**Type**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE car_error_type force AS OBJECT
(
   model       NUMBER,
   v1 NUMBER,
   v2 NUMBER,
   error_text           VARCHAR2(1000)
)
```

Comment: `CAR_DETAILS_TAB_TYPE` doesn't match `number_tab_type` or `car_error_tab_type`. How are those types defined in the database? And the types they are tables of?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have added the sproc body.

Comment: How are the types defined though? Presumably `car_error_tab_type` is a table of an object type, for example, but how is that defined? Please add the `create type` statements for all of the table and object types to the question.

Comment: Try the code posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621638/how-to-call-procedure-with-out-parameter-as-table-type-from-a-java-class

Comment: i have added the type.