# Getting wrong number of argument or type for proc call

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Object type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type cycle_t as object
(
  rk     NUMBER,
  ndt    date,
  ht     varchar2(40),
  be     number(5),
  count  number(20),
  fy     number(2),
  bih    VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Collection type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type cycle_tab as table of cycle_t;
```

PACKAGE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shem.Pkg_Bam_rok AS
    type cycle_tab is table of cycle_t;

    PROCEDURE test_proc(i_cf             IN VARCHAR2,
                        i_acm            IN VARCHAR2,
                        o_res            OUT cycle_tab,
                        o_error_message  OUT VARCHAR2);

END Pkg_Bam_rok;
/
```

BODY:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Pkg_Bam_rok AS

    procedure test_proc(i_cf             IN VARCHAR2,
                        i_acm            IN VARCHAR2,
                        o_res            OUT cycle_tab,
                        o_error_message  OUT VARCHAR2)
    is
        v_be  varchar2(20);
    begin
        SELECT 2 into v_be  from dual;
    end test_proc;

end Pkg_Bam_rok;
/
```

JDBC_CALL :this is call of my proc

```
final String typeName = "cycle_t";
final String typeTableName = "cycle_tab";

// Get a description of your type (Oracle specific)
final StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(typeName.toUpperCase(), connection);        
final ResultSetMetaData metaData = structDescriptor.getMetaData();

CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{call shem..Pkg_Bam_rok.test_proc(?,?,?,?)}"); 
call.setString(1,"asd"); 
call.setString(2,"asd");
call.registerOutParameter(3,Types.ARRAY,typeTableName.toUpperCase());
call.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR); 
call.execute();
```

PLS:00306: Getting error wrong argument or type

EDIT: I tried with normal proc it works but when it is called from package its giving error

Comment: Why you register the third parameter as ARRAY? In your SP it is a table. I think it must be a CURSOR.

Comment: I  have followed  @Horcrux7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621638/how-to-call-procedure-with-out-parameter-as-table-type-from-a-java-class?rq=1 this example